# Pass several parameters in StartLogin function

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, m, powerbi-datasource

I am building a custom connector to connect to our API via OAuth2. This is so we can use our api as a data source to powerbi.

```
    // Resource definition
        Resource = [
            Description = "MyAPI",
            Type = "Custom",
            MakeResourcePath = (env) => env,
            ParseResourcePath = (env) => {env},
            Authentication = [OAuth=[StartLogin = StartLogin, FinishLogin = FinishLogin, Refresh = Refresh]],
    ......
Icons = [
            Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("MyAPI10.png"), Extension.Contents("MyAPI20.png") }
        ],
        Label = "MyAPI"
    ]
in
    Extension.Module("MyAPI", { Resource })
```

I used MakeResourcePath and ParseResourcePath to pass the `Environment` parameter (which is taken as input from the user in power bi site/desktop). This is passed to `StartLogin` to make the OAuth authorize call.

```
  StartLogin = (env, state, display) =>
        let
            resourceUrl = getOAuthUrlFromEnvName(env) & "/oauth/authorize",
            AuthorizeUrl = resourceUrl & "?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
                client_id = getClientIdFromEnv(env),
                response_type = "code",
                state = state, // added by VM
                redirect_uri = redirect_uri])
        in
            [
                LoginUri = AuthorizeUrl,
                CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
                WindowHeight = windowHeight,
                WindowWidth = windowWidth,
                Context = env
            ],
```

I need another parameter as input from the user now. It's called `hostname` in ui. How do I pass `hostname` and `environment` both to `StartLogin` function? I basically need these two variables to construct `resourceUrl`. Any references would be helpful too.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm looking for the same thing, and setting a global variable in the custom connector is not working, or I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass the variables into `StartLogin` function to construct the `AuthorizeUrl`. Instead, you can just declare them as global variables so the `StartLogin` can access them to construct the `AuthorizeUrl`.

e.g.

```
hostname = ...;
environment = ...;
authorize_uri = hostname & "/" & getOAuthUrlFromEnvName(environment) & "/oauth/authorize?"
```

---

```
StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
    let
        authorizeUrl = authorize_uri & "?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
        ...
```

Comment: and how do I assign the hostname and environment? How will the values entered by user end up in them?

Comment: You can refer to this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/tree/master/samples/HelloWorldWithDocs) for how to obtain user input.

Comment: @FoxanNg your example does not seem helpful. You claim these global variables can be set by user input but the example does not show this. Can this even be done? Power query variables are immutable.